# Change the title attribute of raphael objects

Tags: html, tooltip, raphael, customization, title

I'm working with raphael.js to draw and I want to modify the title attribute (change color, font size, etc., ).

```
circle.attr({
    title: 'This is a circle.',
    fill: 'red'
});
```

Here's my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsscuz1a/).

Is there a way to do this? Or maybe add custom tooltips to raphael objects?
Edit: Here's an expected modification: I wanna print *"Hello World"* on my tooltip. *"Hello"* in red, then a *"new line"* character and finally, *"World"* in blue color.

This doesn't work but might help to get an idea on what I'm trying to do.

```
circle.attr({
    title:"<font color="red">Hello</font><br><font color="blue">World!</font>"
});
```

Comment: @RodrigoDela, I've edited to explain the kind of modification I wanna do.

Answer (score 1):

Raphael does not have shorthand functions for this, but you can very easily alter the rendered SVG elements by simple DOM manipulation :

```js
circle.node.onmouseover = function() {
    this.style.cursor = 'pointer'
    this.querySelector('title').textContent = 'This is a new title';
}
```

forked (now actually working) fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/nheL8add/**

---

**Update** : I now realize that you are actually asking : "*does a HTML element title attribute supports HTML*?" (I was totally focusing on changing the title element, not the part efter "Edit"). The answer is no. The title attribute of a circle element is completely the same as any other title attribute in all other HTML elements. But you can use a tooltip script like [**qTip2**](http://qtip2.com/) or similar to get the desired effect. I recommend qtip2 since it support `<SVG>` elements. Skip the title attribute on the circle element itself and use qTip2 instead  :

```
$("#canvas circle").qtip({
  style: { classes: 'tooltip' },
  content: { text: '<font color="red">Hello</font><br><font color="blue">World!</font>' },
  position:{ my:'center center', at:'center center' },    
  show: 'mousemove mouseenter mouseover'    
});
```

yet another forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/ajLnhete/**